# How to create a method to get the Key of a value(string) in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I have an assignment, This is my HashMap initialization.. I can only use standard JAVA API.

```
private static HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> hMap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
```

Is it possible to get the Key of a specified value say getkey(hMap,"today") and it would return the key where today is located..

Aslo is there a way to get the last value of a Key in my HashSet?

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: What is the expected behavior of getKey if multiple keys map to the same value?  You seem to be implicitly assuming that the mapping is injective (or one-to-one).

Comment: Judging by your question and some of your comments, you seem to be asking for many different things. Organize your thoughts and be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But actually you can have more than one keys which has "today". So I return List.toString with keys

```
private static HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> hMap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

public static String getKey(Map<String, HashSet<String>> map, String value) {
    List<String> returnKey = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(s).contains(value)) {
            returnKey.add(s);
        }
    }

    return returnKey.toString();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // put sth to hMap
    System.out.println(getKey(hMap, "today"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is [Google's Guava BiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys. This constraint enables bimaps to support an "inverse view", which is another bimap containing the same entries as this bimap but with reversed keys and values.

If you can't use that, then you're going to have to loop through the maps entry items looking for a match which isn't overly speedy.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use an outside library :(

Comment: @eNetik: is that homework then? Either way, you need to update your question to include such restrictions.

Comment: @eNetik - even ones that are Apache Licensed like the Guava libs?  It allows for commercial and non-commercial development

Answer (score 0):

As generically as possible with nothing but a `Map`.

```
public static <K,V> K getKey(Map<K,V> map,V val){
    for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry:map.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getValue().equals(val)){
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will only return the key of the first value that matches. If you want to return all the keys for a specific value, then you can modify this method to accumulate they keys into a `List` and return that instead.

(Don't get your hopes up for a speedy retrieval...)

Comment: That method doesnt accept a (map , stringvalue) for some reason

Comment: It will accept whatever the `V` in your map is. According to the code in your question that is `HashSet<String>`. This compiles: `Integer key=getKey(new HashMap<Integer,String>(),"foo");`

Comment: My Key is a String however.. String key=getKey(new HashMap<Integer,String>(),"foo"); Does not compile :/ If i change K to String and cast String on entry.getKey(); would that work?

Comment: The second parameter represents the **value** of the map. In my example, the **value** is `String`. They **key** is an `Integer`. In your example, the **value** is a `HashSet`. My answer only answers your first question. It's up to you to iterate over the `HashSet` when it is returned.